# Underscore.js filtering JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have a JSON array like this.

```
[{
 SiteID: 350,
 CompanyList: [{
   CompanyName: "TestCompany",
   CompanyID: 30 }],
SiteName: "Testing"
}]
```

I am trying to _.filter like this.

```
var test = _.filter(jsondata, function(obj) {
  return ~obj.CompanyList.CompanyName.toLowerCase().indexOf('test');
});
console.log(test);
```

But i get undefined error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does your return have a tilde `~` at the beginning?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - because it returns -1, so if I use tilde, it returns 0. If I didn't use tilde, it would return all objects..

Comment: I've never seen that before. Have you tried logging from within the filter function?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to filter on the `CompanyList` array which is the *first element of the `jsondata`*. You also need to complete the test for `indexOf`.

```
var test = _.filter(jsondata[0].CompanyList, function (obj) {
  return ~obj.CompanyName.toLowerCase().indexOf('test') > -1;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cxowamw6/1/)

Comment: But what if the first object of JSON has an empty CompanyList?

Comment: Obviously it won't return anything. What are you trying to do? I thought you were trying to return all companies in the list where the company didn't have "test" in its name... @Calliditas